# Проблемы первых месяцев работы программистом

Tags: php

Привет.

Прошу прощения, мой вопрос выбивается из ряда технических, но я полагаю, задать его здесь - неплохая идея.

Работаю программистом в офисе около месяца, для меня это тяжелое испытание :)
Не только потому, что я в принципе в программировании около года, но и потому, что сама обстановка кардинально отличается от работы дома / кодинга в университете.

Люди, которым есть возможность задать вопрос, постоянно заняты и отвечают неохотно. Система, с которой приходится иметь дело, никак не документированна - все связи, файлы нужно искать вручную каждый раз. Над душой постоянно стоит менеджер, который подгоняет и расписывает каждую задачу поминутно. Никаким обстоятельным code review пока не пахнет, хотя наверняка периодически он будет случаться.

Из-за этой спешки, множества непонятных вещей в голове сумбур, я удивлен, что пока получается укладываться в план. Больше всего беспокоит, что в такой атмосфере, особенно забыв пообедать, ближе к вечеру наступает полный ступор, не могу родить и строчки кода, могу минуту тупить над комментарием для коммита, глаза разбегаются при виде большого текста, сложно отмотать листинг до нужной строки. С утра же наоборот, первый час-два очень продуктивны, все просто и быстро получается.

Вопрос собственно вот в чем. Нормально ли это для начала, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Или что-то конкретно со мной не так? Может быть, есть какие-то методики, как сохранять рассудок в течении всего дня?

Или ждать, чтобы прошло с опытом?

Спасибо.

Comment: в целом трудности подобного рода довольно типичны. Пройдут с опытом, если будете прилагать достаточное упорство. Ненормальным является неохотная реакция ваших коллег. Они должны понимать, что вы с ними делаете одно общее дело, что они сами когда-то были на вашем месте, и что взяв на работу новичка, нужно энное количество времени потратить на его "шлифовку". Но это уже вопрос к ним. 

З.Ы. не "координально", а кардинально

Comment: Я думаю, они понимают, конечно, в целом все ребята хорошие. Но очень занятые, тоже торопяться, у всех куча задач - чувствуется неохота отвечать на вопросы. Однако всегда отвечают - сразу или подходят чуть позже.

И меня все устраивает в этом плане, кроме своей слабо работающей головы под конец дня. Ощущение почти каждый день, как после экзамена по матанализу :)

Comment: Я не знаю, типично это или нет (*для таких выводов, надо в десятке контор посидеть*), но уж точно, что к новичку подход не правильный. Крутясь, как белка в колесе и работая на автомате, вы перестанете развиваться в разных направлениях, энтузиазм быстро пройдёт и познакомитесь с депрессией. Не люблю советовать что-либо в таких ситуациях, может быть, вам и нужно побыть в такой шкуре, а может, нужно сразу делать ноги. Тут очень многое от самого человека зависит, то есть от вас.

Comment: >Я не знаю, типично это или нет (для таких выводов, надо в десятке контор посидеть)

Ну, либо учитывать не только личный опыт, а и опыт других людей. То есть, говоря о типичности, я исхожу не только из собственных ощущений.

Answer (score 1):

По мне, вполне нормальный старт на работе, где уже устоявшиеся рамки программирования и команда.
Другое дело, если Вам тяжело и непривычно. Тут можно посмотреть на разные вещи и прийти к нужному выводу для себя:
 - интересна ли работа;
 - хорошо оплачиваемая работа;
 - есть интересные люди;
 - и т.д.

Все вопросы и мысли Вам будет проще составить по собственному пожеланию\опыту. :)

Я начинал работать в похожем проекте, правда людей там не было, мне просто передали уже сделанный проект на доработку и последующее расширение функциональностей. Так же первые 3-5 месяцев бился с недопонимаением структуры и функций. Сейчас уже более 3 лет прошло, работаем в небольшой команде, намного проще, и уже как семья. :)

Если не хватает общения с персоналом, и он не идет на диалог - тут вряд ли что-то можно сделать, только подключить соц. инженерию и втискиваться в доверие.
Или еще есть разные внерабочие сообщества по интересам, где можно найти ребят по аналогичной специфике работы.

Пожелаю вам удачи, терпения и чуточку везения. ;)

П.С. Не стесняйтесь порой вносить здравые предложения по улучшению процесса разработки, но обязательно имейте ввиду, что это может лечь на ваши плечи чуть ли не целиком. ;)

Comment: Мне тяжело и непривычно, но работа нравится + люди интересные. Если для старта это нормально - значит буду продолжать стараться войти в темп.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какая работа, сколько платят и насколько вы хороший программист. В целях работодателя - увеличить ваше КПД и уменьшить ЗП, ваши же - наоборот, в итоге должны сходиться на золотой середине (в офисах гугла там 70% в сторону прогеров (P.S. им несколько часов, приблизительно часов 20-30, в неделю в любое время разрешается не работать и сидеть над своими проектами пыхнеть)). Если вы говорите, что около года в программировании, то это нормально, скорее всего, лучше пусть сейчас будет тяжело, зато потом будет легче на высокооплачиваемых работах. (Ибо, как правило, там работодатели понимают, что хороших прогеров мало, поэтому и платят много и следят, чтобы не ушли. :))